# Diferencia entre Clean Project, Rebuild Project y Reformat Code en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo esta pequeña duda que diferencia hay entre estas opciones del IDE. ¿Que diferencia existe entre ellas?

[image: Situacion]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Clean Project**: como su nombre lo indica, limpia el proyecto, en realidad lo inicializa previo a una nueva construcción. Al realizar esta acción puedes ver que varios elementos dentro de `app\build` son eliminados, incluso el .apk (android artifact) que se encuentra dentro del directorio `/outputs`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Rebuild Project**: Realiza la misma acción que `Clean Project` pero seguida dela construcción del proyecto.
Esta opción vuelve a generar el contenido de `app\build`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Reformat code**: es una opción para aplicar el correcto formato al código, aplicar espaciado, sangrías, palabras clave, etc. Este reformateo puede aplicarse al texto seleccionado, todo el archivo, o todo el proyecto.

Windows

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Mac:

> <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: gracias por la info ;D

Comment: un placer Eduardo, ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ saludos!

Answer (score 1):

- Un clean borra todos los artefactos de la build.
- Un rebuild limpia toda la build de tu proyecto, es decir lo reinicia como he dicho antes.
- Reformat Code cambia código que pueda estar mal formateado, es decir, este mal tabulado, malas comas.

De esos tres solo recomiendo usar los dos primeros, suelen ser útiles, mientras que la tercera puedes usarla pero en mi caso nunca me ha solucionado nada. Espero haya servido.

Comment: mas tema estetico y de presentacion el reformart no?

Comment: @EduardoMéndez actualizada mi respuesta para que sea más completa, el reformat code no sólo es por estética, también puede ser que de fallos alguna tabulación o algun parametro mal formateado.

Comment: Grande @almartinez ;D

Comment: @EduardoMéndez jajaja, espero te haya servido, como última aportación añado un ejemplo también aquí en stackoverflow del reformat code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411280/how-to-format-code-in-android-studio-intellij